# How do I connect a Tab bar item to another view controller (Objective-C, Xcode 6)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, tabs

Using objective c and Xcode 6, To an existing View Controller that have been created with other objects already laid out, I decided to add a Tab Bar last minute, so I dragged it out of the Object Library and stuck it onto the View Controller at the bottom. I dragged two Tab Bar Items as well out of the Object Library and stuck them on top of the Tab Bar.

Then I created just two blank View Controllers out of the Object Library, and did ctrl + mousepad and attempted to connect each Tab Bar item to a View Controller but doesn't work.

What would be the correct method to assign each Tab Bar Item to a view? Any insight and guidance would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi, try to choose Editor->Embed In->Tab Bar for your viewController. Afterwards you can connect the other view controllers to the Tab Bar Controller

Comment: @BernhardHarrer Is there a way to just do it the way I mentioned? Because, I would like to just add a Tab Bar to an existing view controller that already has a handful of other views connected to it before.

Comment: You can use this controller and select Embed In->Tab Bar